# Remove/add 'index.php' from with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i'm having trouble with my website 
i have WP website installed in root directory
this is 2nd website in subfolder
i'm giving up already 
please help me figuring this out

here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

when i test it this is what i get

```
This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
```

The website loads without /index.php but nothing seems to work
with /index.php all links are working just perfect but stylesheet is not loading, pictures are not loading etc.

please help me solve this i'm already giving up on this

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Also what URL are you going to an where is your htaccess file?

Comment: You are using that `madewithlove` htaccess tester and it tells you that it doesn't support `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` so you have to remove thoses lines if you want to test. It's just a tester. It can't determine if the request is not a dir or file in a tester.